# Partial derivatives igual zero implies $f(x,y)$ constant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I want to prove with richness of details that if $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f_x(x,y)=f_y(x,y)=0$ for all
$(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$

Here is my progress

Fixing $y_0$ and considering
$$g(x) :=f(x, y_0), $$
a real valued fuction of $x$, if I also fix a $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, then I only need to prove that $g(x) =f(x,y_0)=f(x_0,y_0)$

So for every $x\neq0$, I use the mean-value theorem to find a $\overline{x}$ on the interval $] x_0,x[$ such that
$$f(x,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)=f_x(\overline{x},y_0)(x-x_0) $$

But $(\overline{x},y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and since $f_x=0$ in all $\mathbb{R}^2$, I have
$$f(x, y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)\ \ \Rightarrow \ \ f(x, y_0)=f(x_0,y_0)$$

In a similar way, I can first fix $x_0$, consider the function $h(y)=f(x_0,y)$. Fixing now $y_0$, the mean-value theorem allows me to find $\overline{y_0} \in ]y_0,y[$ such that
$$f(x_0,y)-f(x_0,y_0)=f_y(x_0,\overline{y})(y-y_0) $$

Finally, using the hypothesis $f_y=0$, I concluded that $$f(x_0, y)-f(x_0,y_0)=0\ \ \Rightarrow \ \ f(x_0, y)=f(x_0,y_0)$$

Do you agree with me?

Comment: For me seems little over complicated: if derivative of function  is $0$, then it is constant. Without mean theorems. Now consider both variables.

Comment: But we can find non constant functions with derivatives =0

Comment: Such sentences depends on set: I mean open interval. If derivative on open interval is $0$, then can you find function non-constant?

Comment: So should I omit intervals?

Comment: Depends on task stated. If you take function with derivative $f^{'}(x)=0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, then it will constant be on it. Now join this info with another variable. You see, I have nothing against mean theorems, but I do not see necessity of using them here.

Comment: @zkutch how do you propose to prove that theorem even in single variable calculus without resorting to the mean-value theorem? I don't think OP overcomplicated the matter; the mean-value theorem seems very essential to bridge the gap between information about derivatives to information about the original function (also, the derivatives aren't necessarily Riemann-integrable, so we can't use he FTC naively).

Comment: @peek-a-boo what do you think about my argument?

Comment: It's mostly fine, except for small things like in your last line of math when you wrote $f(x_0,y) - f(x_0,y_0) \implies f(x_0,y) = f(x_0,y_0)$, you're missing the "$=0$" on the LHS, so it should be "$f(x_0,y) - f(x_0,y_0) = 0 \implies f(x_0,y) = f(x_0,y_0)$". A similar issue in the middle of your proof. But also, presentation wise, it would be clearer if you just use the mean-value theorem to first prove the single-variable statement that "if $\phi:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ satisfies $\phi' = 0$, then $\phi$ is constant", and then in the 2-variable case, just refer to the lemma.

Comment: This is better than just repeating the same argument using the mean-value theorem again and again.

Comment: Thank you... I also correct the last expression

Comment: @peek-a-boo. "resorting to the mean-value theorem" - what you understand/mean in these words?

Comment: @zkutch you said OP is over-complicating the issue, and that he should use the fact "if the derivative is 0 then the function is constant". My point is that OP is not over-complicating the matter, because the proof of this theorem already makes use of the mean-value theorem. So, my question to you is do you have a simple proof of this theorem which does not use mean-value? (my guess is probably not)

Comment: Sorry what does OP mean?

Comment: @peek-a-boo. Formal answers (several) are even here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2442461/zero-derivative-implies-constant-function-no-mvt-rolles-theorem-etc and  here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645371/proof-that-zero-derivative-implies-constant-function-without-mean-value-theorem .

Comment: @peek-a-boo. As comment length is limited, I continue previous one here. There is also few books in mathematical analysis which suggest this sentence as exercise (Foundations of Mathematical Analysis by Johnsonbaugh, for example).  Less formal, but most geometrically clear answer is using slope concept. And, at last, most exotic answer, that I know is taking integral from equation $dy=0$.